# How to replace the minimum value with another value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have numerical values in A1, B1, C1, D1. I want to replace the minimum of the values in A1, B1, C1, with the maximum between this minimum and D1. Do you have any ideas on how to do that?

For example, say that the values in the cells A1, B1, C1, D1 are respectively

```
1 2 3 4
```

I want to turn it into

```
4 2 3 4
```

I would like to do this for the first 100 rows. Also, I do not want to create a new column, I want the minimum value to be replaced.

So far I figured out the function `ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH(MIN(A1:C1),A1:C1,0),1)`
which gives me the cell number of the cell with the minimum value. Now I just need to figure out how to substitute the value in the cell with the maximum between this value and the value in D1.

Comment: Can you post few sample data as text table then show your desired output.

Comment: Then how it is `2` for second result. As stated, to compare with `D1` it should always be `4` as 4 is maximum.

Comment: `=IF(A1>MIN($A1:$D1),A1,MAX($A1:$D1))` ? You need to insert this four cells to another new range.

Comment: Think it should be `=IF(A1=MIN($A$1:$D$1),MAX($A$1:$D$1),A1)`

Comment: @Harun24hr I do not follow.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal But I do not want to create a new column. Is there a way I can replace the minimum value with the value I want?

Comment: You cannot replace original value using formula, it would create a circular reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have the range in A1:D1

Add the formula to A2.

```
=IF(A1=MIN($A1:$D1),MAX($A1:$D1),A1)
```

And stretch-copy it to D2.

[image]

You cannot replace the original value using formula, it would create a circular reference. You cannot modify the input data using formula - that would be an infinite loop of calculations.

You can use this approach for multiple rows too, you just need to copy the formulas to multiple output rows e.g. on another worksheet.

E. g. if your data sheet is named `Sheet1`, you put this formula to Sheet2:A1

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1=MIN(Sheet1!$A1:$D1);MAX(Sheet1!$A1:$D1);Sheet1!A1)
```

And stretch it 4 cells to the right and 100 rows downwards.

[image: example]

Comment: Sorry, I should have probably been clearer in my question. What if I want to perform this operation for the first 100 rows?

Comment: Add another sheet and copy the formula to the first 100 rows :)

Comment: How do I make sure that on the second sheet, the cells that are referred to come from the first sheet?

Comment: Not sure that I understand, in excel workbook you have a collection of worksheets that you can address by name.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your suggestion then. When you said "Add another sheet and copy the formula to the first 100 rows :)" what exactly did you mean? Because if I add a sheet and then copy the formula in cell A1, Excel complains because it is referencing itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cannot create circular reference.
Try this macro. Copy it into the sheet's VBE code module and run.
Valid datas start in the first row, if not change the value to the corresponding row number in the `i = 1` phrase.

```vb
Sub Somemacro()
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
mincell = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("A" & i & ":C" & i))
mincellcol = WorksheetFunction.Match(mincell, Range("A" & i & ":C" & i),0)
If Cells(i, 4) > Cells(i, mincellcol) Then
Cells(i, mincellcol) = Cells(i, 4)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```